# Subdirectory to Subdomain .htaccess Issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a subdirectory to a subdomainbut it seems that the RewriteBase below it is causing an error 500. How can I make the redirect happen on the subdirectory and still let all the other rules work when on the subdomain?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to mbp subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mbp\.fasttracksites\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mbp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mbp.fasttracksites.com/$1 [R=301,END,QSA]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# MBP Rules
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2&page=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&s=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteBase should never give a 500 error.

The problem is in the none-existing `END` flag you are using. I think you mean the `L` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mbp.fasttracksites.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yeah had it as L before but saw END in a document on mod_rewrite so tried it both give an error 500, here's the URL where this is at: http://www.fasttracksites.com/mbp/

Comment: try removing block of code until the 500 error disappears. 500 errors usually mean you have some syntax-error in your htaccess.

Comment: Got it all the way down to this and still have error 500: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

Comment: From that I would guess that mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: No its on, the following does the redirect but I lose all of the rewrite flags below it:Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to mbp subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mbp\.fasttracksites\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mbp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mbp.fasttracksites.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: Try removing the htaccess and create a new file, and copy-past the rule from this site (or even retype the rules manually). It could be that there are some hidden characters inside the file, which will make apache give a 500. If I copy paste the rules above in a htaccess file, apache doesn't give a 500 error.

Comment: Hey guys, looks like it's an issue with my host (1and1) I called them and apparently they limit the mod_rewrite items fairly heavily and it's whats causing the breaks. Thanks for all the help!